# Item not getting selected in Multiselect List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a list of Accounts on the page and there is an edit button after every Account. When that button is clicked data gets populated in the form below the list. This multi-select box is present in that form.

When the list of account gets loaded and the user selects an account from the list the multi-select box gets populated with the selected elements from the database for that particular account. If the edit button is clicked again without reloading the DOM, the multi-select box does not get populated.

The point is I am selecting the elements using below jQuery code:

```js
var itemValues = $('select[name^="item"]').find('option');
$.each(itemValues, function(key, teamVal) {
  $.each(selectedRow.item, function(key, values) {
    var arrval = teamVal.value.split("_");
    if (arrval[0] == values.teamId) {
      $('select[name^="item"] option[value="' + teamVal.value + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    }
  });
});
```

The statement `$('select[name^="item"] option[value="' + teamVal.value + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");`  only selects the elements for the first time in the multiselect box when the DOM is loaded.

It is not selecting the elements the second time, ie. when the user clicks on the edit button for the same account again. You have to refresh the page. This means the above select statement is not working for the second time.

Comment: Are you using some multi-select plugin for this ?

Comment: Could you please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can see a working example of the problem

Comment: where is this function in the page code? how is it  being called?

Comment: @DavideVitali the function hets called when user clicks on the edit button after the account entry in the accounts list. The forms gets populated with the data for that partucular account, this multiselect is also part of that data

Comment: @MayankPandeyz No

Comment: yes, but how it is called? Something like $('#someid').on('click', 'div', function () { ... }) or what?

Comment: @DavideVitali   this code is inside a function say function abc(), and this function gets called when user clicks on the edit button, on click of button is called, then this code gets called

Comment: I'd rather say YMCA. Please provide the relevant code, we cannot get in your head and just guess things around...

Comment: If those "edit" buttons are generated dinamically, chances are that something goes wrong with the binding. That's why I'm asking

Comment: @Davide OK will provide you the relevant code

Comment: @DavideVitali  Ok will provide you the relevant code

Comment: If you place a breakpoint in your jQuery code does it get fired the second time? If not sounds like you may need to rebind to the list of items after you change it? If the items are being re-generated then they are new to the DOM and won't continue to use any previous bindings.